# Copying a bunch of data to global memory at once In CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, overhead

I want to copy a bunch of data to device from host either at once or as a series of chunks in turn,  it'll affect my algorithm. My question is that which one has more overhead? **I think**, invoking more than one copy operations has more overhead than the other one does; however i just want to know this concept in more details(**thinking** generally doesn't square with the reality:)). If you may show a reference to sort of a document, it would be really appreciated!

Kind Regards,
Ilker

Comment: When you say "overhead", are you asking about fixed, data size independent latency, or something else?

Comment: No no! totally size independent(not important either it is large or small in size). Let's say i've N number of bytes to copy to device from host; my question is which one is faster? either copying all N bytes at once or as a series of chunks such as copy(N/K), copy(N/K), ... i.e. running the copy function for K times. I think latter one is much costlier; but how much more is it costlier than the former one? If copying it as a series of chunks of bytes is 1.2 times costlier than copying it at once; then i may opt for latter solution(copying it as a series of chunks).

Answer (score 1):

If the copies are synchronous (the default), they do incur more overhead because each copy function waits until the GPU is idle before returning.  If the copies are asynchronous, the overhead is a few microseconds, which will only be visible for small memcpy's.

Note that you can specify an asynchronous memcpy with the NULL stream, and you will still get the benefits of CPU/GPU concurrency. (i.e. the CPU can kick off the next memcpy while the GPU is processing the previous ones.)

The CUDA Handbook (which, in the interests of full disclosure, I should say that I wrote) covers this issue in Chapter 6, and the source code includes an app that measures the size of a memcpy that hides the overhead of invoking a memcpy. Check out breakevenMemcpyHtoD.cu in the repository:

https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/tree/master/concurrency

Comment: Very thanks, indeed. Well i see what you mean; however i cannot pass NULL stream, i believe(as you'd done in the code); because i should be notified of that copy operation is completed. Well actually, my goal in asking this question was to keep cpu and gpu busy all the time and async copy seems the only way to me. However there was also another possibility for me, which is, my code at cpu side could accumulate the data until it reaches at a certain level; then could copy it as a bulk instead of a series of chunks. I hope now i am a bit more clear :)

Comment: Async copy is the only way to keep both CPU and GPU busy at the same time, in which case you also must do CPU/GPU synchronization.  You can synchronize *and* keep both both by using CUDA events to do the synchronization.

Comment: Ow i am sorry; yeah you are right, not streams, it would have been events... that's right sorry:)... On the other hand, do you think i should wait for data to be accumulated at the host side for which it'll be able to reach at a certain amount; then i could still copy it asynchronously. By this means, i'll call "memcpyAsync" M times which is relatively small than K times(M << K) to copy the data i mention. Is that logic right? Or you say "Don't complicate the code by adding additional complexity to accumulate the data just for few microseconds hence, simply call memcpyAsync for K times"?